# Android4.2 libdvm.so Can't find the function of dexFileParse

Tags: android, dalvik, dlsym

libdvm.so inside of Android2.3, i can use the code to call dexFileParse
code:
void * handle=dlopen("/system/lib/libdvm.so",RTDL_LAZY);
void *pFunc=dlsym(handle,"dexFileParse");

---

but libdvm.so exports _Z16dexFileParseXXX,i won't get the address of dexFileParse from
dlsym(handle,"dexFileParse").
you say:you can dlsym(handle,"_Z16dexFileParseXXX"), yeah, it will be OK,
but _Z16******XXX is renamed by the compiler of cplusplus,I can't use it when i don't know the compiler of cplusplus

---

How can i call the dexFileParse?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbol changed when the source code was changed from `.c` to `.cpp`.  The `dexFileParse` function is part of libdex, and is not public.  Not only can't you rely on the name mangling [having a specific value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Standardised_name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B), you can't rely on the fact that the function exists or works as you expect it to.

If using a private API is acceptable for your use case, then probing for the function with `dlsym` (i.e. try `dexFileParse`, then `_Z16dexFileParseXXX`) should be fine.  If this isn't acceptable, then you should try to find a public API that handles the problem you're trying to solve.